# How do I loop through multiple tables with jQuery in a html file loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I am trying to parse a response data as html format. The data contains multiple tables (not nested tables). I load the html with ajax and trying to loop through the data with jquery.

The problem is No result when I start with 'table' for looping (I have multiple tables and have no ID for the table.) When I use 'tr' It works well in firefox and chrome but not in IE.

I would like to know how I can loop through these tables.
Here is the code I was trying.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Html table tParser</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){   
        $.ajax({
                url: "htmltables.html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)  
                { 
                 //alert( (html.length));
                 //alert( $(html).find('table').size() );  
                $(html).find('table').each(function(index) 
                { 
                    document.write('<br />'+'<br />'+ 'Table:' + index + '<br />')
                    $(this).find('tr').each(function(index) {
                        document.write('<br />'+'<br />'+ 'Row :' + index + '<br />');                     
                        $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {                                                       
                            document.write($(this).text() + '<br />');
                        });  //td
                    }); //tr    
                });  //table
         } //success
             }); // $.ajax(
  });//$(document).ready(function    

     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>

/*------------------------------ */
/* Here is the sample html file I was trying to parse*/

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yikes, format your code!  indent it 4 spaces please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try

```
$(html).wrap('<span>').parent().find('table')
```

Comment: Thank you, This  works  well in Chrome and Firefox. IE just prints 'Table 0'

Comment: This works in IE now, document.write was the problem.
still one more issue, IE process the table in Reverse order, last table first ?
I use, $(html).wrap('<span>').parent().find('table').each(function(index){
is there anything wrong ?

Comment: Wrapping a table in a span? At least use a div.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the table to a hidden element and then parse it:

```
var wrapper = $('<div>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
// [...]
success: function(html) {
    wrapper.append(html);
    var table = wrapper.find('table');
    alert(table.length); // should be at least 1

    // parse the HTML here

    wrapper.show(); // will reveal the html
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It  works, with some problem
It works in Chrome and Firefox. except "wrapper.show()"
IE it just printing 'Table0', how can I make this work in IE too ?
Why 'table' is not working without appending to DOM, but 'tr' still works ?